# How many objects per day is MongoDB capable of handling?

Tags: performance, mongodb, database-performance, query-performance

I'm about to do some testing with MongoDB. Is the software capable of running an ingest rate of 1 billion objects per day? (~11.5k objects/second) Our hardware is a few years old but decent (multicore, > 8gb of ram, > 1tb storage).

Are there any specific best-practices for optimizing mongodb queries? Are there any methods or functions that are known to be slow?

Thanks,
~Kyte

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to do benchmarking for you. Try the DBA site, maybe. And there is no proper way to answer your question anyways with the information you've provided. 1TB is a **SIZE**, not a speed. You can have 1 terabyte of **PAPER FILES** for all we know, and your per-query access time will be as fast as the geriatric slaves you've hired to fetch the files and OCR them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the mongodb web site for various best practices dealing with performance.  Here is a start:

http://www.mongodb.com/webinar/best-practices-evaluating

But to answer your question, there is nothing in the product that would prevent it from handling your load.  THe rest depends on your documents, network, server hardware, etc.

Hope this helps
Alex Lerner

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the webinar section before